# Check for mic permission on iOS 7 without showing prompt

Tags: permissions, ios7, microphone, avaudiosession

The only documented method for checking mic permission on iOS 7 that I could find is `requestRecordPermission` documented on `AVAudioSession`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/requestRecordPermission:

However, the very act of checking permission using this method will display an alert asking user for permission if user hasn't already made a decision, which can be very undesirable. Is there a work around to check mic permission without showing a prompt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iOS 8, they added a new property to AVAudioSession:

```
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance].recordPermission
```

That returns a `AVAudioSessionRecordPermission`:

```
enum {
   AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionUndetermined     = 'undt',
   AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied           = 'deny',
   AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted          = 'grnt'
};
typedef NSUInteger  AVAudioSessionRecordPermission;
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way in iOS 7.

Comment: It looks like there is a way to check this on both iOS 7 and 8: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31161351/1827383