# Check AVAudioSession record permission status

Tags: ios, ios7, avaudiosession

Is it possible to check the record permission status (if it is granted or not) without initiating standard iOS request flow?

For example, if I would like to know if record permission is granted, but without calling `-requestRecordPermission` on `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]` which will make iOS present prompt to the user about allowing access to the microphone.

I am looking something similar to the CLLocationManager's authorizationStatus kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be lacking in the API. Another user [asked the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615105/check-for-mic-permission-on-ios-7-without-showing-prompt?rq=1) with no replies. Submit an enhancement request to Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 8, they added a new property to AVAudioSession:

```
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance].recordPermission
```

That returns a `AVAudioSessionRecordPermission`:

```
enum {
   AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionUndetermined     = 'undt',
   AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied           = 'deny',
   AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted          = 'grnt'
};
typedef NSUInteger  AVAudioSessionRecordPermission;
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Swift answer:

```
if AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() == .Denied {
    MKAlertViewController().instantaneousAlert(title: "Erreur", message: "Vous n'avez pas autorisé l'application à accéder au micro")
}
```