# iOS check if application has access to microphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, microphone, avaudiosession

With the introduction of iOS 7, applications have to request microphone access when they want to record audio.

How do I check if the application has access to the microphone?
In the iOS 8 SDK I can use the `AVAudioSessionRecordPermission` enum, but how do I check this in iOS 7?

Info:
I don't want to request permission, I just want to check if the app has access to the microphone. (Like Location access):

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39250149/2870477

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In `iOS7` there is no way to get the current status of `microphone authorization`.They have given the enum in `iOS8` as [AVAudioSessionRecordPermission](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AVAudioSessionRecordPermission)

In `iOS7` you have to request permission every time with

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted) {
            NSLog(@"Permission granted");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Permission denied");
        }
    }];
```

The same question has been asked before but there is no such api with which you know current status as in `iOS8`

You can refer [Check for mic permission on iOS 7 without showing prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615105/check-for-mic-permission-on-ios-7-without-showing-prompt?rq=1)

**Solution:**

Another option is you can show the `popup` or ask for permission **first time** and save the states of user option selected in `NSUserDefaults` and than onwards do not ask for permission.
From docs you explicitly do not need to call this if each you do not need to get the permission of user.It will automatically called by  `AVAudioSession` first time when you try to record

> Recording audio requires explicit permission from the user. The first
>   time your app’s audio session attempts to use an audio input route
>   while using a category that enables recording (see “Audio Session
>   Categories”), the system automatically prompts the user for
>   permission; alternatively, you can call requestRecordPermission: to
>   prompt the user at a time of your choosing

Answer (score 87):

You can check the with [recordPermission()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616463-recordpermission?language=objc), which has been available since iOS 8.

Keep in mind that starting with iOS 10, you **must set** the `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` property in your `info.plist` for microphone permissions and include a message for the user. This message is shown to the user at time of the request. Finally, if localizing your app, be sure to include your plist strings for translation.

[image]

**Failure to do so will result in a crash when attempting to access the microphone.**

This answer has been cleaned up again for **Swift 5.x**

```
import AVFoundation

    switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission {
    case .granted:
        print("Permission granted")
    case .denied:
        print("Permission denied")
    case .undetermined:
        print("Request permission here")
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ granted in
            // Handle granted
        })
    @unknown default:
        print("Unknown case")
    }
```

**Objective-C**

I have tested this code with iOS 8 for the purpose of checking for microphone permission and obtaining the current state.

```
switch ([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] recordPermission]) {
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted:

        break;
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied:

        break;
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionUndetermined:
        // This is the initial state before a user has made any choice
        // You can use this spot to request permission here if you want
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

As always, make sure to `import AVFoundation`.

Comment: FYI, the property to add to your info.plist is NSMicrophoneUsageDescription

Comment: @Harris Thanks, my screenshot clipped it but I will make it more explicit

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 3 Complete Solution Code**

```
func checkMicPermission() -> Bool {

        var permissionCheck: Bool = false

        switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
            permissionCheck = true
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
            permissionCheck = false
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (granted) in
                if granted {
                    permissionCheck = true
                } else {
                    permissionCheck = false
                }
            })
        default:
            break
        }

        return permissionCheck
    }
```

Comment: this will not work as `requestRecordPermission ` is invoked async. There will be always `true` returned

Comment: You can use semaphores in objective-c or DispatchGroup in Swift, in this case you can wait for the result, then return it.

Answer (score 11):

There is another way you can try following code for ios 7 and 8 :

```
let microPhoneStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)

switch microPhoneStatus {
    case .Authorized:
        // Has access
    case .Denied:
        // No access granted
    case .Restricted:
        // Microphone disabled in settings
    case .NotDetermined:
        // Didn't request access yet
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What I often end up doing for a quick check on objects working with audio record:

```swift
// swift 5 
static public func isAuthorized() -> Bool {
    return AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio) == .authorized
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted) {
            // Microphone enabled code
        }
        else {
            // Microphone disabled code
        }
    }];
```

And include `<AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>`

Comment: I don't want to request recording permission, I just want to check if the application has access to the microphone (like with location access: ``[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]``)

Comment: It will request for the first time from next time onwards it will not ask again

Comment: So I can check Microphone access just in iOS 8?

Comment: i tried this but it says property requestrecordpermission not found on object type avaudiosession

Comment: can you share a dummy project?

Answer (score 4):

Since none of the other answers here mentioned this, you need to add the permissions to your info.plist. Specifically, add an entry for:

Privacy - Microphone Usage Description

> > For the String value, enter something like: 
> >     (App name) needs access to your microphone.

Otherwise, you get a mysterious crash

Answer (score 3):

import AVFoundation and use the following function

```
var permissionCheck:Bool = false

switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission {

        case AVAudioSession.RecordPermission.granted:
            permissionCheck = true

        case AVAudioSession.RecordPermission.denied:
            permissionCheck = false
        case AVAudioSession.RecordPermission.undetermined:
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (granted) in
                if granted {
                    permissionCheck = true
                } else {
                    permissionCheck = false
                }
            })
        default:
            break
        }
```