# iOS Ask Permission Before Used Page

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need user microphone action(ObjC). If user have this permission, i will open other page. Therefore, i must ask user if user have this permission before use below code and second page.
Is there any option to ask this question programmatically before microphone usage page?

Comment: Below link might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/24981502

Comment: Thank you @RajeshDharani

Comment: Welcome @Begüm Kırkgöz Demirci