# cannot call value of non-function type 'AVAudioSession.RecordPermission'

Tags: swift

I am getting this error: (on switching to swift 4.2 from 4.0)

> error: cannot call value of non-function type
>   'AVAudioSession.RecordPermission'
>                   switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
>                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~

the following code should have no issues according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27751685/9499646)

```
switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
        case AVAudioSession.RecordPermission.granted:
            NSLog("granted")
            hasPermissions = true
            break
        case AVAudioSession.RecordPermission.denied:
            NSLog("denied")
            hasPermissions = false
            break
        case AVAudioSession.RecordPermission.undetermined:
            NSLog("undetermined")
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if allowed {
                        self.hasPermissions = true
                    } else {
                        self.hasPermissions = false
                    }
                }
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
```

I am new to swift and was trying to refactor a flutter plugin, whats the issue here?

Comment: The answer you linked to was wrong (at least for Swift 4). I just fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recordPermission` is a property, not a function. Remove the `()`.